# pandas regex match all items between two sets of white spaces

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How can I match everything to include special characters between exactly 3 white spaces to the left and exactly 3 white spaces to the right of a colon? Example denoted with W as a white space.

Example match:

```
\\s\\s\\sdata\\sstuff:\\s\\sfound\\ssome([%$)Data\\sas\\swhiteSpace\\s\\s\\s
   data stuff:  found some([%$)Data as whiteSpace
```

Example nonMatch:

```
\\s\\sdata\sstuff:\\s\\sfound\\sno\\sdatacause\\sno\\s3\\sspaces\\sbefore\\sor\\safter\\s\\s
  data stuff:  found no datacause no 3 spaces before or after
```

The intent is to expand this to seperate columns from a single column of a pandas dataframe.

Expected output:

```
data stuff                                data stuff 2
found some([%$)Data as whiteSpace         if i had more examples for data stuff 2 it would show here
extra random data to add into a outputdf  if i had more examples for data stuff 2 it would show here
```

Original thought was to use something like this but this doesnt quite work.

```
"(\\s\\s\\s(.*?)\\:\\s\\s(.*?)\\s\\s\\s)"
```

Comment: Can you clarify what characters you want to match?

Comment: i need to match any character possible between exactly 3 white spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this df

```
    col
0   data stuff:   found   some([%$)Data as whiteSpace   1
```

Regex1:

```
df.col.str.extract(':\\s{3}(.*)\s{3}')
```

would return

```
0    found   some([%$)Data as whiteSpace
Name: col, dtype: object
```

That is the content between three white spaces before found and three white spaces at the end before 1.

Where as

```
df.col.str.extract(':\\s{3}(.*?)\s{3}') #note the ? after .*
```

will return

```
0    found
Name: col, dtype: object
```

That is the content between the first and second instances of three white spaces.

If you provide more test cases, it would become clear as to what else do you need the regex to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:^|[^ ])   (.*?)   (?:$|[^ ])
```

Break it down!

- `(?:^|[^ ])` - Match anything that is either **not** a space or **is** the beginning of a line
- `x   (.*?)  x` match anything that is between 3 spaces on either side (x's added so spaces don't disapear)
- `(?:$|[^ ])` match anything that is **not** a space or **is** at the end of a line

[Example in regexr](http://regexr.com/3fkiv)